# Asus Xonar D1 Loses Sound On One Of The Channels

Tags: audio, asus

This is in reference to the question in the link below.

[Asus Xonar D1 looses sound on one of the channels](https://superuser.com/questions/1285181/asus-xonar-d1-looses-sound-on-one-of-the-channels)

Piff suggests installing the following driver. UNi-Xonar-STXII-11.5-v1.80b-r3.

Does anyone know how to get audio through the front panel using this method?

Thanks

Comment: Front panel of what? Are you referring to an internal PC speaker, a set of speaker jacks on the PCs front panel, or something else? It seems a large part of the described issues and solutions deal with one or more portions of that sound card not working at all, and having to route sound around those broken parts to the remaining working parts. If that's the case, is the front panel connector the broken part of your card?